# Get times and cut with SOX

Tags: bash, sed, grep, sox, bc

I have a little problem taking audio times from a simple text file and cutting and audio file with SoX.

I have a time list like:

```
0
4.053
8.879
15.651
19.684
21.853
```

And I need make the audio partition with Sox, as follows:

```
sox NAME.wav NEW_NAME.wav trim "$time" "$duration"
```

To do this I need the Initial time and the Duration. For the Duration variable I jump one line from the lecture and get the next value amb make a substraction:

```
cat FILE.txt | while read line; 
do
end_time=`grep -A 1 $line FILE.txt | sed 1d`
start_time=$line
if [ -z "$end_time" ];
then
    end_time='21.853'
fi
#echo "This is start: $start_time"
#echo "This is end: $end_time"

duration=$(echo "$end_time-$start_time" | bc) 
#echo "DURATION: $duration"
done
```

But I get some errors in the Duration variable, can anyone help me with this script?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it fits your needs but it looks more logical to do it this way:

**FILE.txt**

```
0       4.053
8.879   15.651
19.684  21.853
```

**yourscript.sh**

```
cat FILE.txt | while read start_time end_time; 
do
    if [ -z "$end_time" ];
    then
        end_time='21.853'
    fi
    #echo "This is start: $start_time"
    #echo "This is end: $end_time"

    duration=$(echo "$end_time-$start_time" | bc) 
    echo "DURATION: $duration"
done
```

**Output**

```
DURATION: 4.053                                                                                                                                                          
DURATION: 6.772                                                                                                                                                          
DURATION: 2.169
```

Comment: The difference is in the FILE.txt. I have one single column, but thanks dekkard

Comment: Yes, that's the idea - you put related values on the same line. At least it's more obvious and in a way prevents from forgetting that there should be an even number of values.

Comment: Even getting past the UUOC, any time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. The whole of the above can be replaced with `awk '{print "DURATION:", $2-$1}' file`.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{ if ($1 != 0 )printf "sox NAME.wav NEW_NAME.wav trim \"%s\" \"%s\"\n",  LastTime, $1 - LastTime;LastTime = $1;}' YourFile
```

not easier in awk ? or batch is mandatory (adapt your output with the printf content and any other info)

```
sox NAME.wav NEW_NAME.wav trim "0" "4.053"
sox NAME.wav NEW_NAME.wav trim "4.053" "4.826"
sox NAME.wav NEW_NAME.wav trim "8.879" "6.772"
sox NAME.wav NEW_NAME.wav trim "15.651" "4.033"
sox NAME.wav NEW_NAME.wav trim "19.684" "2.169"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk, this kind of task is what it's designed to do:

```
$ awk '!(NR%2){print "sox NAME.wav NEW_NAME.wav trim", p, $0-p} {p=$0}' file
sox NAME.wav NEW_NAME.wav trim 0 4.053
sox NAME.wav NEW_NAME.wav trim 8.879 6.772
sox NAME.wav NEW_NAME.wav trim 19.684 2.169
```